# Instance variables in Angular component are not working from within a setInterval called function

Tags: angular, setinterval

My Angular 13 component should show a progress bar while an audio file is being played.

I'm trying to increase the progress bar value (runs from 0 to 1) by a calculated interval in a function called with setInterval() to run every 1/100th of a second.

The called function is: **progressTimeBar()**.

```
progressTimeBar(interval: number) {    
    this.p_bar_value = Number(this.p_bar_value + interval);
    console.log('Advanced p_bar_value: ', interval, this.p_bar_value);    
  }
```

The **p_bar_value** instance variable of the component is NOT accessible correctly from within progressTimeBar.
The console log renders it as NaN (that's why I tried to to force the Number() on its calculation - to no avail. Always NaN).
Console:

```
Advanced p_bar_value:  0.002 NaN
```

Btw, the there is an instance variable called interval as well, but accessing it directly in this function using **this.interval** yields the same results - NaN. That's why I am now passing it as an argument.
But I must advance the instance **p_bar_value** as it is bound to the template value of the progress bar!

Here's the component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { VoiceService } from "../../services/voice.service";
import { StreamState } from "../../Utilities/stream-state";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-audioplayer',
  templateUrl: './audioplayer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audioplayer.component.scss'],
  providers: [VoiceService]
})
export class AudioplayerComponent {

  @Input() url: string;

  audioDurationDisplay: string;
  state: StreamState;
  p_bar_value: number = 0;
  totalDuration: number = 0;
  playingNow: boolean;
  timerHandle: any;
  interval: number = 0;
  loaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(public audioService: VoiceService) { 
    // listen to stream state
    this.audioService.getState().subscribe(state => {
      this.state = state;
      console.log('StreamState in Audioplayer updated: ', this.state);
      if (this.state.duration) {
        this.totalDuration = this.state.duration;
        this.interval = 0.01 / this.totalDuration;    
        console.log('Updated TotalDuration from state: ', this.totalDuration);
      }
      if (this.state.ended) {
        clearInterval(this.timerHandle);
        this.p_bar_value = 0;
      }
    });
  }


  ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.url) {
      console.log('this.url received: ', this.url);
      this.CalcTotalDuration();
      this.loaded = true;
    }

    
  }

  CalcTotalDuration() {
    const durationRaw = this.url.slice(this.url.lastIndexOf(".")-4, this.url.lastIndexOf("."));
    this.audioDurationDisplay = durationRaw.slice(0, 1) + ":" + durationRaw.slice(-2);
    const arrRaw = this.audioDurationDisplay.split(":");
    this.totalDuration = (parseInt(arrRaw[0]) * 60) + (parseInt(arrRaw[1])); //Total in seconds
    this.interval = 0.01 / this.totalDuration;
    console.log('Calculated TotalDuration: ', this.totalDuration);
  }


playController() {
console.log('Calling progressTimeBar. totalDuration: ', this.totalDuration, Number.isNaN(this.totalDuration));
console.log('Calling progressTimeBar. interval: ', this.interval, Number.isNaN(this.interval));
console.log('Calling progressTimeBar. p_bar_value: ', this.p_bar_value, Number.isNaN(this.p_bar_value));
    clearInterval(this.timerHandle);
    this.timerHandle = setInterval(this.progressTimeBar, 10, this.interval);

    if (this.state.canplay) {
      this.play();
    } else {
      this.playStream();
    }
    
  }
  

  playStream() {
    this.audioService.playStream(this.url).subscribe(events => {
      this.playingNow = true;
    });
  }

  pause() {
    this.audioService.pause();
    clearInterval(this.timerHandle);
    this.playingNow = false;
  }

  //Restart playing again (resume after pause)
  play() {
    this.audioService.play();
    this.playingNow = true;
  }


  stop() {
    this.audioService.stop();
    clearInterval(this.timerHandle);
    this.playingNow = false;
    this.p_bar_value = 0;
  }


  progressTimeBar(interval: number) {
    this.p_bar_value = Number(this.p_bar_value + interval);

    console.log('Advanced p_bar_value: ', interval, this.p_bar_value);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.timerHandle);
  }

}
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: If at any point either `this.p_bar_value` or `interval` are undefined then it will forever be NaN as the Number constructor is essentially being called recursively with values that aren't numbers. Have you tried wrapping it in a check for both of those values not being undefined to check for this?

Comment: Thanks Alex. What do you mean by "wrapping it in a check"? How would p_bar_value be undefined if it is instantiated with the component: *p_bar_value: number = 0;*?

Comment: There's loads of places in your code when you're not doing things with type safety or checks for undefined, e.g. `this.totalDuration = (parseInt(arrRaw[0]) * 60) + (parseInt(arrRaw[1])); //Total in seconds`  `this.interval = 0.01 / this.totalDuration;` where you could easily be creating things that aren't numbers to pass into a number constructor. Just put some check that those value are numbers in your `progressTimeBar` function and you'll probably find that at some point you're trying to create a number out of things that aren't numbers. One `this.p_bar_value` is NaN, it will always be NaN.

Comment: The above code has probably a pretty good chance of being your issue as parseInt of a non existent array element will return NaN and you never check the length of arrRaw before accessing it.

Comment: @Alex I agree that more robust checks are needed, however, as you can see after those "parse" statements I am calculating this.interval which is passed as a real number and logging the result this.totalDuration which logs as a real number too. It is all numbers until the progressTimeBar function.

Comment: @Alex. The *this.p_bar_value* which is NaN in the progressTimeBar function - has no other place where it is assigned any other value than 0. Also, see the added 3 console.log lines I added in the playController() function - allways showing valid numbers.

Comment: Just move your console.log to above your Number constructor in that function and I expect you will see at some point you're passing in a value that isn't a number.

Comment: could you add logs for all the intermediary steps in `CalcTotalDuration`?

Comment: Yes, I added log statement after every line and all are calculated properly. Alejandro solved this - see his solution. Thank you, Alex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try declaring `progressTimeBar` as an arrow function? We are using it as a callback and we lose `this` scope.

Either

```
    this.timerHandle = setInterval((interval) => { this.p_bar_value += interval }, 10, this.interval);
```

or

```
  const progressTimeBar = (interval: number) => {
    this.p_bar_value = Number(this.p_bar_value + interval);
  }

  this.timerHandle = setInterval(progressTimeBar, 10, this.interval);
```

should work

Comment: Thank you, Alejandro. The first format did not work - the second one did! I just needed to remove the "const" as it is not viable within an Angular class.

Comment: both should work actually, i had some syntactical issues but i edited the code, anyways, i'm glad it worked :)